# KnockoutJS - Sending a form containing the value of a javascript object results in a timeout

Tags: php, javascript, html, symfony, knockout.js

I have a problem that occurs when I try to send a form, if a particular field type is present, the page returns a time out.

I'm using KnockoutJS's mapping plugin to map an object coming from the server. I'm able to modify the object and I want to send it back.

To do so, I created a computed function that returns the result of `ko.toJSON` to which I pass this particular object. Then, this value is put in an hidden input to be sent back to the server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="a" data-bind="value: exportToJSON()" />
```

When I'm sending the form with this input field, I get an error 7:

> Error 7 (net :: ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

Here's a JSFiddle representing my code

http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/4EXSy/17/

I suspect that the problem is caused because the data in the field sent via POST is not escaped ?

**Update 1**

Someone suggested to use ko.mapping.toJSON. However, doing that results in an empty string, see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/4EXSy/18/

**Update 2**

Now, results input is not empty, thanks to @abc123: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/4EXSy/19/. 
However, I still get a timeout when sending the POST Data. You can see the POST data that is sent when I send my form in my code: http://pastebin.com/hNRm4zdZ

**Update 3**

I'm using symfony2 and I'm starting to think that the problem might be linked to something in symfony2 since when I copy and paste the form on a simple .html file, the data gets sent...

**Update 4**

I deleted Symfony2 dev.log, clicked on the button to send the form, got the time out error and unfortunately, the log is still empty.... Also, all the php and apache logs do not show anything...

**Update 5**

I finally decided to test my symfony website on another server and it works on this other server... Now this is getting weird, why isn't it working in my local server ? I'm using MAMP Pro as a local server

Comment: Please review http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html and how to serialize knockout object ko.mapping.toJSON(object);

Comment: when I replace the line with the one you provided, the result is empty.

Comment: @abc123 Here's what I mean: jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/4EXSy/18

Comment: provided you with the answer, sorry it took me so long I am at work.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `ko.mapping.toJSON(self.playersEvaluation)` you cannot access a property of **knockout** without calling the function since it is actually a function.

To get it to return proper JSON please do the following:

```
function appViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.playersEvaluation = ko.observableArray();
    self.exportToJSON = ko.computed(function() {
          return ko.mapping.toJSON(self.playersEvaluation())
    }, this);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/WReza/1/

To use Console Easily: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/WReza/1/embedded/result/

Luckily since you are using the `ko.mapping` plugin this will work because it does the following:

> - All properties of an object are converted into an observable. If an update would change the value, it will update the observable.
> - Arrays are converted into observable arrays. If an update would change the number of items, it will perform the appropriate add/remove actions. It will also try to keep the order the same as the original JavaScript array.

Taken from [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried to modify my code (not in the JSFiddle) and I still get a timeout... If I comment the hidden input field, then the timeout does not exist...

Comment: I updated my question, I think there might be a problem with Symfony2 and some post data format...

Comment: @CoachNono I highly recommend opening a new question, since the data is no longer empty.  you will likely get a Symfony2 expert in a matter of moments that way.